# Group by regexp Google Analytics pie chart

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I have a utm_campaign parameter that is either set to dynamiskNA-* or dynamiskTF-*.

However, the dash is followed by a bunch of IDs, but I only want to show i pie chart with dynamiskNA vs dynamiskTF.

Anyone know if I can do that? See attached image :)

Thanks in advance!
[image: See picture here]

EDIT: What I want to do here is to group all dynamiskNA-* into on group and all dynamiskTF-* into another group and the group by that dimension.

Answer (score 0):

```
dynamisk(NA|TF)\-.*
```

This captures dynamiskNA-{anything} or dynamiskTF-{anything}.

Comment: Yes, I could do that, but where should I put that regex? I cannot find out where to put it?

Comment: You already have one up in your screenshot where you are filtering with Regular Expression. Just replace that with what I've provided.

Comment: That regex does not decide the how the data is grouped. It is only for filtering data. See the red arrow, that is where the grouping happens...

Comment: I think nyuen misunderstood your question - you cannot group data in GA the way you intend (i.e. display everything that starts with dynamiskNA as one chunk of the pie and everything that starts with  dynamiskTF as a second).

Comment: Thanks @EikePierstorff! Just about to say that that wasn't possible as well. @stianIp, I think the closest you would get is to do some sort of grouping with custom segments in your standard reports.

Comment: But I need to do this exact pie chart. How can I make it happen?